# How create table with spring data cassandara?

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have created my own repository like that:

```
public interface MyRepository extends TypedIdCassandraRepository<MyEntity, String> {
}
```

So the question how automatically create cassandra table for that? Currently Spring injects `MyRepository` which tries to insert entity to non-existent table.

So is there a way to create cassandra tables (if they do not exist) during spring container start up?

**P.S.** It would be **very nice** if there is just config boolean property without adding lines of xml and creation something like *BeanFactory* and etc. :-)

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and would love to know. So far I've created a custom repository method called "createIfExists" where I've instantiated a `CreateTableSpecification` with `ifNotExists()` called on it. I manually call the method after spring-data-cassandra initialization.

Answer (score 12):

Overide the getSchemaAction property on the AbstractCassandraConfiguration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "com.example")
public class TestConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Override
    public String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "test_config";
    }

    @Override
    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraOperations cassandraOperations() throws Exception {
        return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm creating the `SessionBeanFactory` manually (to override spring-boot's) and setting the schema action. However, it doesn't appear to have made any difference and I still get "InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table mytable".

Answer (score 10):

You can use this config in the **application.properties**

```
spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS
```

Answer (score 7):

You'll also need to Override the  [getEntityBasePackages()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/config/java/AbstractCassandraConfiguration.html#getEntityBasePackages--)  method in your AbstractCassandraConfiguration implementation.  This will allow Spring to find any classes that you've annotated with @Table, and create the tables.

```
@Override
public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
    return new String[]{"com.example"};
}
```

Comment: I suppose presently spring-data-cassandra 1.5M1 it is not working. Can you confirm on.

Comment: @AllahbakshAsadullah yes its not working with version 1.5.1. What version did you use instead?

Answer (score 4):

1. You'll need to include [spring-data-cassandra](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-cassandra/2.0.0.RELEASE) dependency in your [pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) file.
2. Configure your **TestConfig.class** as below:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:Your .properties file here" })
   @EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "base-package name of your Repositories'" })
   public class CassandraConfig {

   @Autowired
   private Environment environment;

   @Bean
   public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
       CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
       cluster.setContactPoints(env.getProperty("contactpoints from your properties file"));
       cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("ports from your properties file")));
       return cluster;
   }

   @Bean
   public CassandraConverter converter() {
       return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
   }

   @Bean
   public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {
       CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
       session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
       session.setKeyspaceName(env.getProperty("keyspace from your properties file"));
       session.setConverter(converter());
       session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS);
       return session;
   }

   @Bean
   public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
       return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
   }

   @Bean
   public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() throws ClassNotFoundException {
       CassandraMappingContext mappingContext= new CassandraMappingContext();
       mappingContext.setInitialEntitySet(getInitialEntitySet());
       return mappingContext;
   }

   @Override
   public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
       return new String[]{"base-package name of all your entity annotated 
   with @Table"};
   }

   @Override
   protected Set<Class<?>> getInitialEntitySet() throws ClassNotFoundException {
       return CassandraEntityClassScanner.scan(getEntityBasePackages());
   }
   }
   ```

   This last *getInitialEntitySet* method might be an Optional one. Try without this too.
3. Make sure your *Keyspace*, *contactpoints* and *port* in **.properties** file. Like :

   ```
   cassandra.contactpoints=localhost,127.0.0.1
   cassandra.port=9042 
   cassandra.keyspace='Your Keyspace name here'
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after digging into the source code located in `spring-data-cassandra:3.1.9`, you can check the implementation:

```
org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SessionFactoryFactoryBean#performSchemaAction
```

with implementation as following:

```
protected void performSchemaAction() throws Exception {

    boolean create = false;
    boolean drop = DEFAULT_DROP_TABLES;
    boolean dropUnused = DEFAULT_DROP_UNUSED_TABLES;
    boolean ifNotExists = DEFAULT_CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;

    switch (this.schemaAction) {
        case RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED:
            dropUnused = true;
        case RECREATE:
            drop = true;
        case CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS:
            ifNotExists = SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS.equals(this.schemaAction);
        case CREATE:
            create = true;
        case NONE:
        default:
            // do nothing
    }

    if (create) {
        createTables(drop, dropUnused, ifNotExists);
    }
}
```

which means you have to assign `CREATE` to `schemaAction` if the table has never been created. And `CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS` dose not work.

---

More information please check here: [Why `spring-data-jpa` with `spring-data-cassandra` won't create cassandra tables automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69203058/why-spring-data-jpa-with-spring-data-cassandra-wont-create-cassandra-tables)