# How to initialize Cassandra keyspace and tables with Spring boot

Tags: cassandra, spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

I am using Cassandra as a datasource in my Spring boot application and would like to initialize the database before the application starts.

Up to now what I have done is, I have defined a class "CassandraConfiguration" extending "AbstractCassandraConfiguration" class as in the examples which you can see below and I have a repository extending "CassandraRepository". When I create the keyspace and the table myself, the application works fine.

However, I want to create the keyspace and tables automatically while application is starting. In order to do that, I supplied a schema.cql file under resources folder but I could not make that script work.

Does anyone have any idea what can I do to create the keyspace(s) and tables automatically?

Thanks.

Edit: I am using Cassandra 2.0.9, spring-boot 1.3.2.RELEASE and datastax cassandra driver 2.1.6 versions.

CassandraConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:cassandra.properties" })
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "bla.bla.bla.repository" })
public class CassandraConfiguration extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;


    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints( environment.getProperty( "cassandra.contactpoints" ) );
        cluster.setPort( Integer.parseInt( environment.getProperty( "cassandra.port" ) ) );
        return cluster;
    }


    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }


    @Bean
    public CassandraConverter converter() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new MappingCassandraConverter(cassandraMapping());
    }


    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return environment.getProperty( "cassandra.keyspace" );
    }


    @Bean
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {

        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
        session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
        session.setKeyspaceName(environment.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace"));
        session.setConverter(converter());
        session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);

        return session;
    }


    @Override
    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED;
    }
}
```

Comment: With spring boot 1.3 the configuration is much simpler, see this: http://flnjworkingnotes.blogspot.com/2016/01/tutorial-connecting-to-cassandra-using.html, for example.

Comment: My problem is not mapping of the objects but rather creation of the tables automatically if the table is not there in advance.

Answer (score 6):

If you are still having problems with this, in **Spring Boot 2 and SD Cassandra 2.0.3** you can do this straightforward Java configuration and setup everything out of the box.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.repository")
public class DbConfigAutoStart extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    /*
     * Provide a contact point to the configuration.
     */
    @Override
    public String getContactPoints() {
        return "exampleContactPointsUrl";
    }

    /*
     * Provide a keyspace name to the configuration.
     */
    @Override
    public String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "exampleKeyspace";
    }

    /*
     * Automatically creates a Keyspace if it doesn't exist
     */
    @Override
    protected List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceCreations() {
        CreateKeyspaceSpecification specification = CreateKeyspaceSpecification
                .createKeyspace("exampleKeyspace").ifNotExists()
                .with(KeyspaceOption.DURABLE_WRITES, true).withSimpleReplication();
        return Arrays.asList(specification);
    }


    /*
     * Automatically configure a table if doesn't exist
     */
    @Override
    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;
    }


    /*
     * Get the entity package (where the entity class has the @Table annotation)
     */
    @Override
    public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
        return new String[] { "com.example.entity" };
    }
```

And you are good to go

Comment: works also with lower versions (spring boot 1.5.10 and cassandra 3.0.16).

Answer (score 4):

Your return type ***BasicCassandraMappingContext()*** might be deprecated. Use

```
@Bean
public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    CassandraMappingContext mappingContext= new CassandraMappingContext();
    mappingContext.setInitialEntitySet(getInitialEntitySet());
    return mappingContext;
}
@Override
public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
    return new String[]{"base-package name of all your entity, annotated 
with @Table"};
}

@Override
protected Set<Class<?>> getInitialEntitySet() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return CassandraEntityClassScanner.scan(getEntityBasePackages());
}
```

Instead of,

```
@Bean
public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
}
```

also set:

```
session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED);
```

and Exclude:

```
@Override
public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
    return SchemaAction.RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED;
}
```

get reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357372/how-create-table-with-spring-data-cassandara/46610702#46610702).

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with `spring-boot 1.5.10.RELEASE` and `cassandra 3.0.16` but you can try downscaling the versions. To create the keyspace you can import the keyspacename from you `application.yml` or `application.properties`. Using the `@Table` annotation your tables should be generated automatically provided you have set the entity base package.

```
@Value("${cassandra.keyspace}")
private String keySpace;

@Override
public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
    return new String[]{"com.example.your.entities"};
}

@Override
protected List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceCreations() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            CreateKeyspaceSpecification.createKeyspace()
                    .name(keySpace)
                    .ifNotExists()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got it working by adding setKeyspaceCreations(getKeyspaceCreations()) to the CassandraClusterFactoryBean Override and also make sure to enable @ComponentScan.

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.PlainTextAuthProvider;
import com.datastax.driver.core.policies.ConstantReconnectionPolicy;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.*;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.keyspace.CreateKeyspaceSpecification;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.keyspace.DropKeyspaceSpecification;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.keyspace.KeyspaceOption;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;



@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "com.company.domain.data")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration{
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contactpoints}") private String contactPoints;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port}") private int port;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}") private String keyspace;

@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.username}") private String userName;
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.password}") private String password;
@Value("${cassandra.basepackages}") private String basePackages;


@Override protected String getKeyspaceName() {
    return keyspace;
}
@Override protected String getContactPoints() {
    return contactPoints;
}
@Override protected int getPort() {
    return port;
}
@Override public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
    return SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;
}
@Override
public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
    return new String[]{"com.company.domain.data"};
}

@Override
public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
    PlainTextAuthProvider authProvider = new PlainTextAuthProvider(userName, password);

    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster=new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();

    cluster.setJmxReportingEnabled(false);
    cluster.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
    cluster.setPort(port);
    cluster.setAuthProvider(authProvider);
    cluster.setKeyspaceCreations(getKeyspaceCreations());
    cluster.setReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(1000));

    return cluster;
}


@Override
protected List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceCreations() {

    CreateKeyspaceSpecification specification = CreateKeyspaceSpecification.createKeyspace(keyspace)
            .ifNotExists()
            .with(KeyspaceOption.DURABLE_WRITES, true);

    return Arrays.asList(specification);
}



@Override
protected List<DropKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceDrops() {
    return Arrays.asList(DropKeyspaceSpecification.dropKeyspace(keyspace));
}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are based on `AbstractCassandraConfiguration` from `spring-data-cassandra`. If you use `spring-boot` then it can auto-configure Cassandra for you and there's no need to extend `AbstractCassandraConfiguration`. However, even in this case you need to do some work to automatically create the keyspace. I've settled on an auto-configuration added to our company's spring-boot starter, but you can also define it as a regular configuration in your application.

```java
/**
 * create the configured keyspace before the first cqlSession is instantiated. This is guaranteed by running this
 * autoconfiguration before the spring-boot one.
 */
@ConditionalOnClass(CqlSession.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.data.cassandra.create-keyspace", havingValue = "true")
@AutoConfigureBefore(CassandraAutoConfiguration.class)
public class CassandraCreateKeyspaceAutoConfiguration {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CassandraCreateKeyspaceAutoConfiguration.class);

    public CassandraCreateKeyspaceAutoConfiguration(CqlSessionBuilder cqlSessionBuilder, CassandraProperties properties) {
        // It's OK to mutate cqlSessionBuilder because it has prototype scope.
        try (CqlSession session = cqlSessionBuilder.withKeyspace((CqlIdentifier) null).build()) {
            logger.info("Creating keyspace {} ...", properties.getKeyspaceName());
            session.execute(CreateKeyspaceCqlGenerator.toCql(
                    CreateKeyspaceSpecification.createKeyspace(properties.getKeyspaceName()).ifNotExists()));
        }
    }
}
```

In my case I've also added a configuration property to control the creation, `spring.data.cassandra.create-keyspace`, you may leave it out if you don't need the flexibility.

Note that `spring-boot` auto-configuration depends on certain configuration properties, here's what I have in my dev environment:

```yaml
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      keyspace-name: mykeyspace
      contact-points: 127.0.0.1
      port: 9042
      local-datacenter: datacenter1
      schema-action: CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS
      create-keyspace: true
```

More details: [spring-boot and Cassandra](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#data.nosql.cassandra)