# Create Table Using POJO class spring data cassandr

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

Create Table from Casssandra POjo class using spring data Cassandra is there any tag to create a table definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use annotation **@Table** from *org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table*  and also use **@PrimaryKey(value = "id")** if your pojo have attribute of *id*.
For an **CassandraConfiguration**.class, follow my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357372/how-create-table-with-spring-data-cassandara/46610702#46610702).