# Why `spring-data-jpa` with `spring-data-cassandra` won't create cassandra tables automatically?

Tags: jpa, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I'm using `spring-data-cassandra:3.1.9` and the properties looks like :

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      keyspace-name: general_log
      session-name: general_log
      local-datacenter: datacenter1
      schema-action: CREATE
```

- Cassandra version: `apache-cassandra-4.0.1`
- spring-boot: `2.4.7`
- spring-data-jpa: `2.4.9`
- spring-jdbc: `5.3.8`
- spring-orm: `5.3.8`

My entity looks like:

```
@ApiModel(description = "Audit log")
@Entity
@Table(name = "audit_log")
@org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table("audit_log")
public class AuditLogPO implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKeyClass
    public static class Id implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @ApiModelProperty(value = "业务标识")
        @Column(name = "business_key")
        @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 1, ordering = Ordering.ASCENDING)
        private String businessKey;
        // setters & getters ...
    }

    @javax.persistence.Id
    @PrimaryKey
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
    @Transient
    private Id id;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "业务分区")
    @Column(name = "business_partition")
    @org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Column(value = "business_partition")
    private String businessPartition;
    // getters & setters ...
}
```

After running this application, table `audit_log` will not be created automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, after digging into the source code located in `spring-data-cassandra:3.1.9`, you can check the implementation:

```
org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.SessionFactoryFactoryBean#performSchemaAction
```

wich implementation as following:

```
protected void performSchemaAction() throws Exception {

    boolean create = false;
    boolean drop = DEFAULT_DROP_TABLES;
    boolean dropUnused = DEFAULT_DROP_UNUSED_TABLES;
    boolean ifNotExists = DEFAULT_CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;

    switch (this.schemaAction) {
        case RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED:
            dropUnused = true;
        case RECREATE:
            drop = true;
        case CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS:
            ifNotExists = SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS.equals(this.schemaAction);
        case CREATE:
            create = true;
        case NONE:
        default:
            // do nothing
    }

    if (create) {
        createTables(drop, dropUnused, ifNotExists);
    }
}
```

which means you have to assign `CREATE` to `schemaAction` if the table has never been created. And `CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS` dose not work.

---

Unfortunately, we've not done yet.

`SessionFactoryFactoryBean#performSchemaAction` will be invoked as expected, however tables are still not be created, why?

It is because `Spring Data JPA` will add entities in `org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.CassandraRepositoryFactoryBean#afterPropertiesSet`(`org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext#addPersistentEntity(org.springframework.data.util.TypeInformation<?>)`). But `performSchemaAction` method will be invoked in `SessionFactoryFactoryBean`. And all of these two `FactoryBean`s do not have an order and we do not know who will be firstly invoked.

Which means if `SessionFactoryFactoryBean#afterPropertiesSet` has been invoked firstly, probably no `Entity` is already there. In this circumstance, no tables will be created automatically for sure.

---

And how to create these tables automatically?

One solution is that you can invoke `SessionFactoryFactoryBean#performSchemaAction` in a bean of `ApplicationRunner` manually.

First of all, let's create another class extends from `SessionFactoryFactoryBean` as:

```
public class ExecutableSessionFactoryFactoryBean extends SessionFactoryFactoryBean {
    @Override
    public void createTables(boolean drop, boolean dropUnused, boolean ifNotExists) throws Exception {
        super.createTables(drop, dropUnused, ifNotExists);
    }
}
```

Next we should override `org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractCassandraConfiguration#cassandraSessionFactory` as:

```
@Override
@Bean
@Primary
public SessionFactoryFactoryBean cassandraSessionFactory(CqlSession cqlSession) {
    sessionFactoryFactoryBean = new ExecutableSessionFactoryFactoryBean();

    // Initialize the CqlSession reference first since it is required, or must not be null!
    sessionFactoryFactoryBean.setSession(cqlSession);

    sessionFactoryFactoryBean.setConverter(requireBeanOfType(CassandraConverter.class));
    sessionFactoryFactoryBean.setKeyspaceCleaner(keyspaceCleaner());
    sessionFactoryFactoryBean.setKeyspacePopulator(keyspacePopulator());
    sessionFactoryFactoryBean.setSchemaAction(getSchemaAction());

    return sessionFactoryFactoryBean;
}
```

Now we can create an `ApplicationRunner` to perform the schema action:

```
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner autoCreateCassandraTablesRunner() {
    return args -> {
        if (SchemaAction.CREATE.name().equalsIgnoreCase(requireBeanOfType(CassandraProperties.class).getSchemaAction())) {
            sessionFactoryFactoryBean.createTables(false, false, true);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please refer this doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/#cassandra.schema-management.initializing.config

But you still need to create keyspace before excuting the following codes:

```
@Configuration
public class SessionFactoryInitializerConfiguration extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

  @Bean
  SessionFactoryInitializer sessionFactoryInitializer(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

    SessionFactoryInitializer initializer = new SessionFactoryInitializer();
    initializer.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

    ResourceKeyspacePopulator populator = new ResourceKeyspacePopulator();
    populator.setSeparator(";");
    populator.setScripts(new ClassPathResource("com/myapp/cql/db-schema.cql"));

    initializer.setKeyspacePopulator(populator);

    return initializer;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify this behavior in your `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      schema-action: create-if-not-exists
```

Although, you will need to create the keyspace (with appropriate data center / replication factor pairs) ahead of time.

Comment: `spring.cassandra.schema-action = create_if_not_exists` now